# 2D Collision & Stop in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple scene in 2D. The right yellow box is the "Player", while the green & brown thing is the "Obstacle".

Player has a `BoxCollider2D`, `RigidBody2D` and a C# script named `Hero.cs` attached to it. `BoxCollider2D` enabled `Is Trigger`; `RigidBody2D` enabled `Is Kinematics`; other settings are left in default values.

Obstacle has only a `BoxCollider2D` with `Is Trigger` enabled.

and here is the `Hero.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {
    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
        if(Input.GetKey("left")) {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
        } else if(Input.GetKey("right")) {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        Debug.Log("Colliding");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        Debug.Log("Triggering");

    }
}
```

Only "Triggering" appears in Console Log.

**My question is:** What should I add to make the "Player" inaccessible to the "Obstacle" (no need to bounce away)?

Note: Using Unity 4.5

---

Update: After I set `Gravity Scale` to **0**, collision detection works, but in a strange way. The "Player" go sideway during collision. Watch this [YouTube video for action](http://youtu.be/fTT6RNxCvA0).

I expect the Player only go along X or Y axis. What did I miss ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### IsTrigger

Triggers let other colliders pass through without any collision happening. They are only triggering an event, hence the name.

If you disable `IsTrigger` for both objects, you will get collisions and the corresponding events are fired.

More infos here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

### IsKinematic

Kinematic rigidbody colliders will only collide with other non-kinematic rigidbody colliders.
Have a look at this matrix http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollisionsOverview.html

Disable `IsKinematic` and move the player with [`MovePosition`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) if you don't want to use force values to move the player.

Comment: I removed `isTrigger` for both objects and `isKinematic` for the "Player". However, gravity starts to apply and the "Player" falls down. How can I cancel out the gravity?

Comment: @Raptor Set `GravityScale` to `0` for your `Rigidbody2D`

Comment: @Raptor Are you using `MovePosition` as I suggested or `Translate` like shown in your question?

Comment: I missed your `MovePosition` point. Now works perfectly! thanks very much.